# How to download economic data from FRED with C++ into txt file?

Tags: c++, json, api

I have created a function to write to a text file with hardcoded data points:

```
void writeData(){
  ofstream dataFile;
  dataFile.open ("input.dat");
  dataFile << "0 0 0.001\n1 0.25 0.1\n2 0.5 0.05\n3 0.75 0.4";
  dataFile.close();
}
```

I would like to do the same with FRED data from an API:

```
https://api.stlouisfed.org/fred/series/observations?series_id=DGS10&frequency=w&api_key=...
```

However, I can't find any way to download that data (from its JSON format) into a txt file through C++. I would be grateful for any help on how to resolve this.

Comment: You will need to use a JSON library to parse the output. Library suggestions are off-topic, though.

Comment: Oh, so I can't use raw code? Which library would I have to download?

Comment: @TomAllen You can use raw code (libraries are raw code too). But unless you feel like reinventing the wheel, it's easier to use a library,

Comment: Thank you @john. I guess I'll go find a library then!